# Apache/MySQL connection issue, throws Unable to connect php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo error

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am building a simple DataBase but i can't get a connection from apache to MySQL

Here is my code :

```
<?php  
DEFINE ("DB_USER", "root");
DEFINE ("DB_PASS", "1234ninja");
DEFINE ("DB_HOST", "localhost");
DEFINE ("DB_NAME", "test3");
$mysql = @mysqli_connect("DB_HOST", "DB_USER", "DB_PASS", "DB_NAME") 
    OR die("Unable to connect ". mysqli_connect_error());
echo "Great!";
?>
```

> **Error message:** Unable to connect php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed:

Comment: Remove error suppressor `@` from `@mysqli_connect`

Comment: Gives me the same error as before

Comment: don't use quotes on defined variables (CONSTANTS) `"DB_HOST"` should be `DB_HOST` etc

Comment: @bansi you mean constants

Comment: @Dragos exactly. lot of people don't understand word _constant_

Comment: GUYS you're amazing! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this `mysqli_connect` line to: (Remove quotes around constants)

```
$mysql = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) OR die("Unable to connect ". mysqli_connect_error());
```

---

**Remember:** Using constants with quotes will let constants be printed as string instead of replacing the values.

Comment: Thanks for the help!